# Magento: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user 'DBUSER'@'%' to database 'DBNAME'

Tags: sql, database, magento

I've been banging my head off the wall for hours with this problem. Can anyone help please? I've not been able to find anything online about it.

I've installed the latest version of magento and added a few stores and simple products, and everything seems to be working fine until trying to add associated products to a configurable product. It lets me add the configurable product but then when I try to add associated products to it, it shows this error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user 'DBUSER'@'%' to database 'DBNAME'

It appears to me to be a privileges issue, but not sure how to resolve it. The site is hosted on heart internet and I can't find how to manage privileges. What's confusing me though is why it's letting me add simple products but not configurable ones.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a privileges issue.

grant_create_temporary_tables,
grant_create_view,
grant_create_routine,
grant_trigger

sorted the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Goto magento dir `/app/etc/` and open local.xml. here
check database `username ,database name,database user password`

Comment: delete all file from var/cache.hope it is cache issue

Comment: Deleting all files in var/cache/ hasn't helped

Comment: check any local.xml file under /app/etc/ just like  local.xml_bak or local.xml.bak.if exists then delete them

Comment: there are no other files under /app/etc/

Comment: check dbuser and database password is proper..Also DB user name have  read ,write all permission for that database