# Error when trying to save a product : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, magento

I have just set up my first magento site and when creating a product I get the error below:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user 'USERNAME'@'%' to database 'DBNAME',
query was:
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `catalogrule_product_price_tmp` ( `grouped_id` varchar(80) NULL COMMENT 'Grouped ID' , 
  `product_id` int UNSIGNED NULL COMMENT 'Product ID' , 
  `customer_group_id` smallint UNSIGNED NULL COMMENT 'Customer Group ID' ,
  `from_date` date NULL COMMENT 'From Date' , `to_date` date NULL COMMENT 'To Date' , 
  `action_amount` decimal(12,4) NULL COMMENT 'Action Amount' ,
  `action_operator` varchar(10) NULL COMMENT 'Action Operator' , 
  `action_stop` smallint NULL COMMENT 'Action Stop' , 
  `sort_order` int UNSIGNED NULL COMMENT 'Sort Order' , 
  `price` decimal(12,4) NULL COMMENT 'Product Price' , 
  `rule_product_id` int UNSIGNED NULL COMMENT 'Rule Product ID' , 
  `from_time` int UNSIGNED NULL default '0' COMMENT 'From Time' , 
  `to_time` int UNSIGNED NULL default '0' COMMENT 'To Time' , 
 INDEX `IDX_CATALOGRULE_PRODUCT_PRICE_TMP_GROUPED_ID` (`grouped_id`) ) COMMENT='CatalogRule Price Temporary Table' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
```

I don't know why this is happening. A similar post seems to suggest it might be a privileges issue but doesn't explain how to implement this fix.

grant_create_temporary_tables, grant_create_view, grant_create_routine, grant_trigger

[Magento: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user 'DBUSER'@'%' to database 'DBNAME'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038023/magento-sqlstate42000-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1044-access-denied-f)

I don't have enough reputation to comment on that issue and try to get a more detailed answer so I created a new one, I hope that's ok.

Interestingly it doesn't happen on another site I set up which is exactly the same except I imported the sample data on that one.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Hi, sorry what code exactly please?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the SO post your referenced is correct, log onto your mysql server as root or a another user with `Grant Options`.  Then run this for your magento user:

`Grant CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, CREATE VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, Trigger on DBNAME.* to 'USERNAME'@'%';`

`Flush privileges;`

This will allow your magento user to create temp tables, etc...

Comment: I like the answer because we don't often see the rights listed out, limits to just the database in question, and **doesn't** include `WITH GRANT OPTION` ... and flushes