# Magento Error: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: magento

I have a Magento Error number and I have Checked from /httpdocs/var/report
Did not understand whats the issues, I have cleared my browser cached and nothing helped ..

```
a:4:{i:0;s:87:"
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
";i:1;s:2681:"
#0 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com.au/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(53987): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com.au/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(54460): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com.au/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(52674): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com.au/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(53730): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com.au/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(54566): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com.au/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(29302): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com.au/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(29243): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com.au/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(11744): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com.au/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(11774): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com.au/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(11759): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com.au/httpdocs/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache.php(53): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com.au/httpdocs/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Cache.php(455): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com.au/httpdocs/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Cache.php(497): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com.au/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(20890): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
#14 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com.au/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(22503): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
#15 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com.au/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(22383): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com.au/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(20120): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
#17 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com.au/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(20050): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#18 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com.au/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com.au/httpdocs/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}
";s:3:"url";s:10:"/index.php";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

My var/report writable permission with 777

Comment: Google the error message, `Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"`

Comment: I have the correct db setting but still getting this.

Comment: If you're getting that message, then something seems to be wrong though.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102896/magento-down-exception-error-sqlstate28000-1045-access-denied-for-user or http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19516/access-denied-when-trying-to-connect-to-database  = Your database login credentials are messed up or permissions are set so root access is not allowed to be used for user database access for security reasons. It's highly specific, no doubts as to what's happening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento: SQLSTATE\[42000\]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user 'DBUSER'@'%' to database 'DBNAME'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038023/magento-sqlstate42000-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1044-access-denied-f)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that localhost is correct, you need to check your database for the existence of the user 'admin' and make sure this user has permissions read and write on that particular database.

This is not a file permissions issue at all, it sounds like a strictly database related issue.

Comment: User permissions (priveleges) within mysql, definitely. There's more to permissions than just file systems.